# React/Next clock example not working on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I've been trying to learn react and next.

Using this clock example given here on [codepen](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/amqdNA?editors=0010), found in the react docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class).

I tried implementing it on a local site.

Clock.js - in /components

```
export default class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

index.js - in /pages

```
import Clock from '../components/Clock'

export default () => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <div id="contentWrap">
      <div><Clock /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Running npm run dev then going to localhost:3000, it will initially load but it wont update each second like on codepen.

Have I missed something somewhere that allows it to update?

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors? 404s? Your issue resembles the sort of thing you'll see if the server-side rendering worked but the client-side mount did not take place.

Comment: The code appears to be correct. It works - is there any error message on the console? Is the interval active - can you add a console.log() call to the tick function?

Answer (score 1):

It is failing because you forgot to import the 'Header' component.

```
import Header from 'path/to/header'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in a test Next.js app that I just set up, and after I commented out the `<Header/>`, it worked as expected, with a ticking clock.

I think the most likely issue is that React is not initializing client-side, which could be due to a number of reasons:

- Do you have noscript or a similar extension that could block client-side js?
- Do you have a custom express server that may be interfering with downloading the next.js bundle?
- Have you tweaked the Next.js webpack config?
- Could the `<Header/>` be throwing an error?
- Is there any other code running client side but not server-side that could possibly have an error? (Probably in a `componentDidMount()` method, or possibly a branch in a `getInitialProps()`.)